# How to design a CSS for a centered floating confirm dialog?

Tags: html, css, dialog, alignment, center

I'm looking for a way to display a confirm dialog that's always centered on the page, and floating over the page.

Tried that, but it's not 'always centered' at all, since the position is fixed:

```
.Popup
{
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10%;
    left: 27%;
    z-index:50;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #FFF6BD;
    border:2px solid black;
}
```

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try using this **CSS**

```css
#centerpoint {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
}

#dialog {
    position: relative;

    width: 600px;
    margin-left: -300px;

    height: 400px;
    margin-top: -200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="centerpoint">
    <div id="dialog"></div>
</div>
```

**#centerpoint** should be the container div of the dialog

*Note* that the **#centerpoint** DIV should be inside the **body** element or inside elements that **don't have a *position: relative;* property**

Comment: I tried it, it works in IE, Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera.

Answer (score 35):

CSS3 transform can be used to avoid hardcoded width and margins:

```css
    .dialog {
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
      -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
      -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
      transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    }
```

[Example usage](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/06/25/nifty-modal-window-effects/)

Comment: You need `position: fixed;` for this to work, when I tried using position: absolute it went halfway out on the left.

Answer (score 23):

Compared to @Toma's answer, you can do it on one element

```css
#theDiv {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: -100px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: -25px;
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="theDiv" />
```

This allows you to place it anywhere on the page regardless of parent containers and their `position` properties.

Answer (score -1):

```
.Popup
{
width:400px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
```

That's horizontal alignment; vertical alignment is a little trickier.
Just Google around for "css vertical center" or something.

Comment: That only centers the dialog in it's parent container. But it doesn't float it over the page.