# Four Equal Boxs with Floating Middle Element

Tags: html, css

Currently I am making a page where I have 4 divs each taking 50% width and height.
I would like to make a div where a box can float at the exact center of the page overlapping these elements.
 This is the coding so far.

```
    <html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div style="background-color:red; width:50%; height:50%; float:left">
</div>

<div style="background-color:blue; width:50%; height:50%; float:right">
</div>

<div style="background-color:green; width:50%; height:50%; float:left">
</div>

<div style="background-color:orange; width:50%; height:50%; float:right">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Providing JSFIDDLE will be useful

Comment: maybe absolute positioning? for these types of questions you should always make a jsfiddle.

Comment: try absolute positioning with top 50% and minus-margin of the half of your element use the same for left side and it should be in the middle

Comment: As the comment say, if you want a center div **without afecting** the rest of the divs it has to be `absolute` positioned, also remember to provide a `z-index` to that element. One last thing, try to use [clearfix hack](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) to wrap your four floating boxes, to prevent weird behavior

Answer (score 4):

Absolute positioning would seem to be  the most obvious solution.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.center {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #663399;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color:red; width:50%; height:50%; float:left"></div>
<div style="background-color:blue; width:50%; height:50%; float:right"></div>
<div style="background-color:green; width:50%; height:50%; float:left"></div>
<div style="background-color:orange; width:50%; height:50%; float:right">
  <div class="center"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should try absolute positioning. Here is another SO question where someone asked how to center a popup dialogue. Similar to what you are doing. [How to design a CSS for a centered floating confirm dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205457/how-to-design-a-css-for-a-centered-floating-confirm-dialog)
Look at the answers provided by Steve Robbins and Cristian Toma. Those I think might help you.